# How to Inherit multiple models in odoo 10

Tags: odoo-10

Does anyone know how to inherit multiple models in odoo 10?

I think the below code is right?

```
class Test(models.Model):    
    _inherit = ['hr.employee','hr.employee.category']
```

Answer (score 1):

First the answer of your question is YES. but to inherit multiple class `_name` property is required .
three types of inheritance is possible in odoo

```
_inherit = 'model_1'
_inherit = _inherit = ['model_1', 'model_2']
_inherits = {'res.partner': 'partner_id'}
```

we can inherit model with or without _`name` 
So what about our '_name' property

> If the _name as the same value as the inherited class it will do a
>   basic inheritance.
>
> If you forget to add the `_inherit` you will redefine the `model` If
>   your class `_inherit` one model and you set a `_name` different it
>   will create a new `model` in a new database table.
>
> If your class inherit many model **you have to set** `_name` if your
>   override an existing model this way you may have some trouble, it
>   should be avoided. It is better to use this to create new classes that
>   inherit from abstract model.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this:

> class Test(models.Model):
>
> ```
> _name = 'hr.employee'
>
> _inherit = ['hr.employee','hr.employee.category']
> ```